# What's the difference between the 2 different Rules pages in admin?

Tags: 7, rules

What's the difference between the Rules shown under `Structure > Content Types > My type > Rules` and `Config > Workflow > Rules`? The first one is from [Entity Rules](http://www.drupal.org/project/entity_rules) (= "*Instead of adding entity related events to Reaction Rules you are able to select which Rules will fire from the bundle management page*").

These pages don't look the same. When do I use one instead of the other (to send emails when nodes are added/edited)?

Comment: use the second one, the first one doesn't appear to me.

Comment: The first one is from https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_rules  "Instead of adding entity related events to Reaction Rules you are able to select which Rules will fire from the bundle management page."   ... I still don't understand the difference.

Comment: There isn't a difference in terms of what they can do. Any rule you make in one place you can also make in the other. Entity rules gives you a different place to edit rules and a way to set more fine-grained permissions. Both of the answers essentially say the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

**Entity Rule is not alternate to Rules**

- It simply acts as component which is, it allows you to set certain conditions and action on it and then this component can be picked by rule to run on certain event.
- It gives another interface for rules action on "Entities" so you do not have to have rule administration permission if you belong to a role who has administration permission for certain entities.

> When do I use one over the other (to send emails when nodes are
>   added/edited)?

- If you want a user role with administration permission of content, and you do not want to confuse or simply give them permission to see all rules on site but you still want them to configure their entity specific rule, use entity_rule module.
- You can also it for sanity of configurations, as it will bundle rules specific to entity on entity page, keeping default rules page more cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

The *Rules* located at `Config > Workflow > Rules` are from the typical [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module.

The *Rules* you see under `Structure > Content Type > My type > Rules` are related to the fairly new [Entity Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_rules) module (great module, though only an alfa version for D7 for now). Refer to [this video](http://www.sixmiletech.com/content/entity-rules-exposing-rules-power-without-rules-complexity) for a great introduction about it.